# craco' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, sanity, craco

I have downloaded a project from github and need to run it but it says craco not recognized i tried to install craco but face following error

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN Found: postcss@7.0.39
npm WARN node_modules/postcss
npm WARN   dev postcss@"^7.0.39" from the root project
npm WARN   75 more (css-blank-pseudo, css-declaration-sorter, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional postcss@">=8.0.9" from postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN node_modules/tailwindcss/node_modules/postcss-load-config
npm WARN   postcss-load-config@"^3.1.0" from tailwindcss@2.2.17
npm WARN   node_modules/tailwindcss
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: postcss@8.4.16
npm WARN node_modules/postcss
npm WARN   peerOptional postcss@">=8.0.9" from postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN   node_modules/tailwindcss/node_modules/postcss-load-config
npm WARN     postcss-load-config@"^3.1.0" from tailwindcss@2.2.17
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usman\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-23T11_57_33_182Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the log, towards the end it says it took a long time because you were proabably using a proxy. Try again after turning off your proxy as a step 1... ?